# Python find closest neighbors to a value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe or list. I want to find the closest values and their index to a given value.

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':[20,24,35,38]})

val = 26 

val_idx = df.iloc[(df['num']-val).abs().argsort()[:2]]
```

Present output (val_idx):

```
    num
1   24
0   20
```

Expected output (val_idx):

```
    num
2   35
1   24
```

Comment: Please edit your post with a proper definition of `df` [mre]

Comment: also I believe you should have `val` instead of `input`? and `val_idx` instead of `idx`?

Comment: @Julien I edited my q. In the above list, 26 is closer to 24, 35. I am surprised you picked 20,35.

Comment: No I meant 20. 26 is closest to 24 and 20, not 24 and 35.

Comment: @Mainland I'm afraid I do not understand the question, are you trying to find the top two values and return their index given a `val`? Because the distance between 26 and 24 is 2 and the distance between 26 and 35 is 9 and distance between 20 and 26 is only 6.

Comment: From the data you've presented, the solution is to emit `idx` and `idx+1`, with boundary checks at each end.  You would have seen this already, so I think we need a more complete problem description.

Comment: @Simon My actual problem is finding closest interpolated value. So, when I have 26, I should use 24, 35 to interpolate.

Comment: @Prune What you suggested could work for 26. In the same problem, If I change the `val` to 32. It would pick 35, because it is closest value. So, by your logic, its neighbors going to be 35 (idx) and 38 (idx+1). Even here I want to get the 26 and 35.

Comment: Filter for the minimum non-negative difference, or max non-positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'num':[20,24,35,38]})
val = 26 

# subtract to get differences
test = np.absolute(np.subtract(val, df["num"]))

# get index
idx = np.argmin(test)
# Condition
idx = np.where(df["num"][idx] > val, [idx-1, idx], [idx, idx+1])

print(idx)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([20,35,33,24,38,43],columns=['num'])
dic = df.to_dict()['num'] 
# {0: 20, 1: 35, 2: 33, 3: 24, 4: 38, 5: 43}

val = 26

upper = {k:v for k,v in dic.items() if v >= val}
# {2: 35, 3: 77, 4: 33, 8: 38, 9: 43}
uppest_index = max(upper,key=upper.get)
# 2

lower = {k:v for k,v in dic.items() if v <= val}
# {0: 20, 1: 6, 5: 24}
lowest_index = min(lower,key=lower.get)
# 3
```

```py
idx = [lowest_index, uppest_index] # [3,2]
```